# Query for similar phrases

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to match 'United States of America' with 'United States' in SQL?

I have the country with the name 'United States' stored in the database.
The query below should retrieve the item from the database with the name 'United States'.

```
SELECT * FROM `countries` WHERE `name` LIKE '%United States of America%'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
where 'United States of America' like concat('%', name, '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you should look into an elastic search database. It has the functionality for partial filters.

Otherwise you could do the following via dynamic sql:

1. Split the string by spaces/delimiter
2. Using joins, (1 is match, 0 is not match) for a given word
3. Total the number of matches (you can pivot or target the columns via a sum operand, but its probably simpler to just sum the values in the target named columns since you're already going to use dynamic sql)

   - if the total number of matches = word count, you have an absolute match (100% match, possible mis-order)

     - For non-absolute matches, calculate the certainty by dividing the sum / number of words (absolute is 100%)
4. Select the top (1) for this list, group by the original word, and order by the certainty.

Alternatively, you can do a what @Gordon said for a simpler, one time solution